# Making sample application like twitter in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am making sample application like twitter. This includes "FeedsCell" which contents Profile image and HTML content text. To Render HTML content I am using UIWebView component.

HTML Content includes JS script. Click able content using `<span>` tag

Following is sample script and `<span>` tag I am using

```
<script>function ignoreclick(){window.location = "ignoreclick";}</script>

<span onclick='return ignoreclick();' style="font-size:12px; font-family:Helvetica; color:rgb(57,142,189); padding:0px; font-weight:bold; word-wrap:break-word;">Click Me</span>
```

All is working fine Unless I rendered around 60-70 feeds, then It start giving low memory warning and @ around 110 it get crash due to low memory.

If I don't add UIWebView, able to run application for more than 200+ feeds without low memory. so seems like its consuming memory with UIWebView.

To Load HTML content I am using `loadHTMLString:htmlstring` api and seems like it may be one of a reason for memory consumption. so can anyone help me to find out why this memory consumption is too much for UIWebView. and If I need to achieve above behavior what approaches need to be taken. have gone through all sample code where using label / textview to render html content, but they are not getting fit with above requirement.

Comment: Are you dequeueing your cell's correctly? can you post the of your `UITableViewDataSource`?

Comment: You can't really use UIWebViews in UItableCells - it just doesn't work correctly from our experience. You have to find another way to display the cell.

Comment: You can use Instruments to check the memory allocation, it will also help you to figure out the best way to minimize memory usage.

Comment: FeedsCell* feedsCel = (FeedsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
   if (feedsCel == nil) 
   {
    feedsCel = [[[FeedsCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:identifier feed:currentFeed delegate:self] autorelease]; }

Comment: Have checked with Instruments and memory heakup is there when UIWebView comes in picture.